# use geoip with nginx logs in fluentd

Tags: nginx, geoip, fluentd

I'm trying to use geoip with nginx logs in fluentd.
as for nginx, I'm using the following filter:

```
<filter *.nginx>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
    <record>
    log ${ if ( !record['log'].match(/"upstream_cache_status": "HIT"/).nil? ) then  record['log'].gsub(',"upstream_response_time ":','') else record['log'] end  }
    @timestamp ${require 'time'; a=record['log'].match( /\"time_local\": \"([0-9.]*)\"/); if !a.nil? then Time.at(a[1].to_f).utc.iso8601(3) else record['@timestamp'] end }
  </record>
</filter> 
<filter *.nginx>
  @type parser
  format json
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
</filter>
```

as for geoip in fluentd, I used:

```
<filter *.nginx>
  @type geoip
  geoip_lookup_key        true_client_ip
  enable_key_country_code geoip_country
  enable_key_city         geoip_city
  enable_key_latitude     geoip_lat
  enable_key_longitude    geoip_lon
  flush_interval          5s
</filter>
```

as a result I get the following output:

```
{
  "_index": ".hicham",
  "_type": "forever",
  "_id": "AWJOoZ1cPXjXRJAPgU2P",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "log": "IP - - [22/Mar/2018:16:53:54 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"curl/7.47.0\" \"-\"\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "container_name": "nginx",
    "@service": "nginxService",
    "@timestamp": "2018-03-22T16:53:54.939Z",
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1521737634939
    ]
  }
}
```

So there is no geoip fields in the output.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your config should look something like this for the geoip filter to work

```
<filter nginx.access>
   @type geoip
   geoip_lookup_keys    true_client_ip

   # geoip2_database   "/path/to/your/GeoLite2-City.mmdb" (using bundled GeoLite2-City.mmdb by default)
   # Specify backend library (geoip2_c, geoip, geoip2_compat)

    backend_library geoip2_c


    <record>
       city            ${city.names.en["true_client_ip"]}
       latitude        ${location.latitude["true_client_ip"]}
       longitude       ${location.longitude["true_client_ip"]}
       country         ${country.iso_code["true_client_ip"]}
       country_name    ${country.names.en["true_client_ip"]}
       region_name     ${subdivisions.0.names.en["true_client_ip"]}

       # GeoJSON (lat lon as array) is useful for Kibana's bettermap.
       # ex. [-122.05740356445312, 37.4192008972168]
       location_array     '[${location.longitude["true_client_ip"]},${location.latitude["true_client_ip"]}]'
    </record>

    # To avoid get stacktrace error with `[null, null]` array for elasticsearch.
    skip_adding_null_record  true

    flush_interval          5s

   </filter>
```